flutter go router builder
I am trying to develop a project with flutter web, but the unexpected null value error is written on the screen, and in the console, the relevant error-causing widget was:

Builder:file:///Users/mertyavuz/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/go_router-14.1.4/lib/src/builder.dart:256:9

Router config:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:hotor_web/view/authentication/login/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:hotor_web/view/authentication/register/register_screen.dart';
import '../../view/management/screen_management.dart';

class AppRouterConfig {
  late final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          return const ScreenManagement();
        },
        routes: <RouteBase>[
          GoRoute(
            path: 'login',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const LoginScreen();
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: 'register',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const RegisterScreen();
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: 'admin',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const LoginScreen();
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: 'openlearnings',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const ScreenManagement(initialPage: 2);
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: 'activelearnings',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const ScreenManagement(initialPage: 1);
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: 'help',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const ScreenManagement(initialPage: 3);
            },
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: 'settings',
            builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
              return const ScreenManagement(initialPage: 4);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}

Register screen:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hotor_web/core/base/view/base_view.dart';
import 'package:hotor_web/core/constants/images.dart';
import 'package:hotor_web/view/authentication/register/pages/register_screen_one.dart';
import 'package:hotor_web/view/authentication/register/view_model/register_view_model.dart';

import '../../../core/base/state/base_state.dart';
import '../../../core/services/register/register_service.dart';
import 'pages/register_screen_three.dart';
import 'pages/register_screen_two.dart';

class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterScreen({super.key, this.initialPage = 0});
  final int initialPage;

  @override
  State<RegisterScreen> createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends BaseState<RegisterScreen> {
  final RegisterService registerService = RegisterService();
  final RegisterViewModel _viewModel = RegisterViewModel();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _viewModel.pageController = PageController(initialPage: widget.initialPage);
    print("PageController initialized with initialPage: ${widget.initialPage}");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Building RegisterScreen with context: $context");
    return BaseView(
      viewModel: _viewModel,
      onPageBuilder: (context, dynamic viewModel) {
        print("Inside onPageBuilder with viewModel: $viewModel");
        return scaffoldBody();
      },
    );
  }

  Scaffold scaffoldBody() {
    print("Building scaffoldBody");
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        width: screenWidth(),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 5,
              child: Image.asset(
                AppImages.loginBackground.imagePath,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 5,
              child: PageView(
                controller: _viewModel.pageController,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                children: const [
                  RegisterScreenOne(),
                  RegisterScreenTwo(),
                  RegisterScreenThree(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Register screen one:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
import 'package:hotor_web/core/components/form_widgets/management/validate_management.dart';
import '../../../../core/base/state/base_state.dart';
import '../../../../core/components/form_widgets/dropdown_form_widget.dart';
import '../../../../core/components/form_widgets/text_form_widget.dart';
import '../../../widgets/step_progress_widget.dart';

class RegisterScreenOne extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterScreenOne({super.key});

  @override
  State<RegisterScreenOne> createState() => _RegisterScreenOneState();
}

class _RegisterScreenOneState extends BaseState<RegisterScreenOne> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("dynamicHeight: ${dynamicHeight(0.1)}");
    print("dynamicWidth: ${dynamicWidth(0.7)}");
    print("currentTheme: $currentTheme");
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: dynamicHeight(0.1),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          progress(),
          SizedBox(
            height: dynamicHeight(0.05),
          ),
          FormBuilder(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: dynamicWidth(0.7),
              child: const Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      //* Name
                      TextFormWidget(
                        hintText: "Ad",
                        title: "Ad",
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                        identifierName: "name",
                        validationType: InputValidationType.text,
                        width: 250,
                        labelVisibility: true,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                      TextFormWidget(
                        hintText: "Soyad",
                        title: "Soyad",
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                        identifierName: "surname",
                        validationType: InputValidationType.text,
                        width: 250,
                        labelVisibility: true,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const TextFormWidget(
                    hintText: "Eğer yok ise 'Yok' yazabilirsiniz.",
                    title: "E-posta",
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                    identifierName: "email",
                    validationType: InputValidationType.text,
                    width: 520,
                    labelVisibility: true,
                  ),
                  DropDownFormWidget(
                    identifierName: "jobTag",
                    hintText: "İş Tanımı Seçiniz",
                    title: "İş Tanımı",
                    items: ["e", "s"], // ViewModel'den gelen liste
                    labelVisible: true,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Padding progress() {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: dynamicWidth(0.1),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const StepProgressWidget(
            currentPage: 1,
            totalSteps: 3,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: dynamicHeight(0.02),
          ),
          //* Title
          Text(
            "Bilgilerinizi girerek kayıt olma işlemine başlayabilirsiniz.",
            style: currentTheme.textTheme.bodyLarge,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Open the browser dev tools, network tab and filter by XHR. Do you see any error there? Perhaps a CORS error?

I just realized something, I think the problem is not because of the api, I deleted the code that I sent a request to the whole api and I still get the same error
I'm getting an error due to go router I think I'm updating the question can you look again
